# How to remove lock that prevents me from deleting a table

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I am revisiting databases after quite a while.   I have setup a very basic MySQL database that has one table, but I cannot alter or drop the table.   I keep getting an error message in MySQL Workbench saying something like:

"DROP TABLE 'flaskr-db'.'user'   Error Code 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get .....

Is there an easy way to fix this ?

Is there an easy way to list the locks and kill them ?   The database is not a production database, only a small test one that I have setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we need to kill the process which cause the deadlock.

We found the locks by combing trough the output from:

```
show engine innodb status;
```

This spits out a crap-ton of information. The relevant section is in the TRANSACTIONS section. In your output the relevant problem seems to be:

```
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 15505085, query id 909492456 junoa....
```

To kill it you need to execute by using the "thread id #" specified -- in this case:

```
kill 15505085
```

also if you are facing the issue on local machine , you can restart the server but it is not recommended if the database is running on server. First try to kill the process.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.   I did try to delete the database earlier, but had no luck, however I have just logged in and the database has finally gone.   I am guessing that the lock's expire after a certain amount of time.   This unfortunately means that I did not get to try your solution, but thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When I issued the kill command I got this error `You are not owner of thread 326117`